# How I can allow user draw curve and control its shape using C++

Tags: c++, mfc, mouse

I want my program to allow user to draw lines and curves based on the mouse events
I did  do the drawing line option but I can't figure how I took the control points and the start/end points of the curve from the user and how I  could allow him do modifications on it 
could any one help me with that and how in general I can control the shapes that drawn by the user for example the program knows when user select specific shape to be delete or resized
I can't imagine the whole idea please help me if you have any tutorials or examples that describe that

I am using visual studio 2010 C++ to code my program as MFC project

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do some research into bezier curves.

Comment: It looks like [GDI+ supports Beziers](http://www.functionx.com/vccli/gdi+/bezier.htm).